# Ember.js / nested json / cannot get data displayed

Tags: json, ember.js, timestamp, nested

making first attempt to master Ember.js atm. I'm trying to make a simple CMS, but for some reason I have a problem with getting any data from json displayed. I've already switched from Fixture to RESTAdapter, but I am still stuck with

> Error: assertion failed: Your server returned a hash with the key timestamp but you have no mapping for it.

Here's my js code:

```
 App.Store = DS.Store.extend(
      {
 revision:12,
 adapter: 'DS.RESTAdapter'
      }
     ); 

 App.Menucategory = DS.Model.extend({
       timestamp: DS.attr('number'),
       status: DS.attr('string')       
});

  App.MenucategoryRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
       model: function() {
               return App.Menucategory.find();
       }
});

DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
  url: <my url>
});

DS.RESTAdapter.configure("plurals", {
  menucategory: "menucategory"
});
```

Trying to access it with:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="menucategory">
    {{#each model}}
{{data}}
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

My json structure:

```
 {
"timestamp": 1366106783,
"status": "OK",
"data": [
{
"name": "starters",
"id": 1
},
{
"name": "main dishes",
"id": 2
}]}
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Your JSON should have a root, as per [conventions](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_json-conventions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the RESTAdapter expects your API to be in a specific format, which your API doesn't conform to, if you can modify your API, you need to get it to return in this format, otherwise you'll need to customize the adapter.

Expected Format (based on your JSON):

```
{
  "menucategory": [
    {
      "name": "starters",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "main dishes",
      "id": 2
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "timestamp": 1366106783,
    "status": "OK",
  }
}
```